# Good javascript widget for streaming data

Tags: javascript, streaming, widget

I have a requirement to show a stream of data via Javascript. Watching an http log file in real-time would be a good example. The data is in fact nested JSON but it could be forced into a table-like structure. The data source would need to be an AJAX call executed periodically (WebSockets would be better but it needs to support non HTML5 browsers). The data should appear to be streaming rather than just refreshing each time the AJAX call is made.

Ideally, it would be good to be able to do things like set filters onto the data as it streams through (either clientside or as part of the AJAX call).

My requirement is pretty specific but other sphere's where this kind of widget could be useful:

- Stock trades
- Realtime-news
- Twitter updates

I may have to write it myself but I'd prefer to use something that's already out there.

Having a way to pause and restart it would also be good.

Answer (score 0):

How about [orbited](http://www.orbited.org/)?

Comment: Orbited looks great, although this requirement is more about the clientside than the serverside.

Comment: That said, it's an open question as to the best way to pass data from server to client.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this [jQuery Twitter streaming widget](http://www.myphpetc.com/2009/11/jquery-twitter-streaming-widget-in-30.html)?